# ngrok error when registering Twilio phone number

Tags: ubuntu, go, twilio, ngrok

I'm following [Twilio's quick start guide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/node) and am getting an error when running the following command in my console:

```sh
twilio phone-numbers:update "<MY_TWILIO_NUMBER>" --sms-url="http://localhost:1337/sms"
```

The error looks like this:

```sh
H: not foundngrok: 1: ����
./ngrok: 2: H__PAGEZEROx__TEXT0-0-__text__TEXT3�: not found
./ngrok: 2: ./ngrok: 2: ��R@�: not found�__rodata__TEXT@�: not found

./ngrok: 1: �#: not found
./ngrok: 2: __symbol_stub1__TEXT: not found
./ngrok: 4: �: not found
./ngrok: 5: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I've not been able to find anything similar to this by Googling any part of the error. I have literally no idea how to proceed.

I first tried running the `twilio` command, which installed `ngrok` and then threw the error. I've since downloaded the zip file from the `ngrok` website and unzipped it into the project folder, but it throws the same error. I can run other commands (e.g. `./ngrok help`) successfully.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, using `ngrok` v2.3.35, `twilio-cli` v2.6.0 and `node` v10.19.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current work around I'm using:

1. Run `ngrok` in a terminal:

```sh
ngrok http 1337
```

2. Get the `ngrok` external address (e.g. `https://1234567890ab.ngrok.io`)
3. Go to https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming, click on the phone number you're testing and set the external address from step 2 as the messaging webhook address.

Note that you'll need to do this *every time you restart ngrok*, as the external address will change each time.